# Firebase firestore doesn't initialize fields of kotlin data classes when they are marked 'private'

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, data-class

If I use a `private` field in my `data class`, Firebase is unable to initialize it. Is it a bug or is this the intended behavior? Couldn't find anything in the documentation about it.

Comment: It uses JavaBeans conventions which requires public getters and setters. If your field is private, that means the getters and setters generated by kotlin will also be private.  Also read: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html

Comment: @DougStevenson Firebase doesn't necessarily require getters and setter, but it *does* require public access. So you can either have a public getter/setter for a field or mark the field itself as public.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Kotlin generates the getters and setters by default and doesn't expose publicly the "backing field" that actually holds the data (as discussed in the doc link above).  This is a pretty big deviation from Java.

Comment: Agreed. I just wanted to clarify that Firebase would take a public field too.